# Free java or flash file browser for photogallery

Tags: php, mysql, file, browser, local

I'm about to develop a small web gallery, where it's supposed to be possible to upload several pictures at a time and then add some info abut the pictures.So I need a free java or flash local file browser that can pass me some info of the pictures that gets uploaded so that I can create some SQL entries for each picture.

The platform for the project will be PHP and MySQL.

Any good recommendations?

Comment: You do not need local file browser. It is built into every web browser.

Comment: I need to be able to select several pictures or entire folders at a time. I don't want to browse for each picture.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org).

From the feature list:

- Upload multiple files at once by ctrl/shift-selecting in dialog
- Javascript callbacks on all events
- Get file information before upload starts
- Style upload elements with XHTML and css
- Display information while files are uploading using HTML
- No page reloads necessary
- Works on all platforms/browsers that has Flash support.
- Degrades gracefully to normal HTML upload form if Flash or javascript is unavailable
- Control filesize before upload starts
- Only display chosen filetypes in dialog
- Queue uploads, remove/add files before starting upload

Comment: I'm gonna look further into SWFUploader soon - it looks promising !